# Can touchsight detect a trickster creature under "hide from the world?"

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic, character-templates, dreamscarred-press

A [trickster creature](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/trickster-creature) is using its "hide from the world" feature.

> Hide from the World (Sp): At will, for one round per HD. This glamer functions like invisibility, except that it masks image, scent, and sound alike, concealing the subject from all senses except touch.
>
> Hide from the World renders the recipient immune to detection by blindsense, blindsight, faerie fire, glitterdust, invisibility purge, tremor sense, scent, and see invisibility. It can be detected by true seeing and any other divination spell with a successful caster level check (DC 15+ the trickster creature’s CR), it can also still be tracked using mundane means.
>
> A trickster creature can choose to allow a creature to perceive it.

Can a psion using [touchsight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/t/touchsight/) detect it?

Answer (score 5):

**RAW, Yes**

Touchsight functions by sense of (telekinetic) touch, which is the one sense that Hide from the World does not cover.  Additionally, it's not one of the (many) things that Hide From The World specifically makes you immune to detection by.

RAW, This one's pretty straightforward.

**Except...**

While touchsight isn't one of the things that Hide From The World is specifically defined to protect against, that's not actually useful data.  The Trickster Creature came out in the Book of Monster Templates (Rite Publishing, Aug 2010 or so).  Touchsight comes from Psionics Unleashed (Dreamscarred Press, Dec 2010 or so).  Powers and spells usually do not include lists of monster feature interactions (like specifying that touchsight specifically not work against Hide From the World).  Even if the two third-party publishers were paying attention to one another, there's nowhere in particular that the interaction would be stated.  Pure RAW is not particularly helpful here.

What we do have is comparative level of power.  Touchsight is a 3rd-level power, available to 5th-level psions.  That makes it equivalent in power to things like Invisibility Purge, rather than things like True Seeing.  Hide From The World protects against effects at the tier of Invisibility Purge, and even True Seeing requires a caster check when trying to overcome it.  If Touchsight does work against Hide From The world, then that's effectively a specific vulnerability that the creature type has against people who happen to have taken that that specific ability (and one of the three classes that can qualify for it).

**And at your table?**

The point of Trickster Creature is to be an annoying creature who messes with the players, who they *cannot find* (until his rounds-per-day runs out, or they manage to stumble into him), in spite of having generally effective anti-invisibility powers on hand.  Even for high-level characters, deploying abilities that generally no-sell all forms of illusion and concealment, the Trickster Creature has a chance of evading detection.  If that is not the experience you want to visit on your players, then that's not a template you should be using.  If it *is* an experience you want to visit on your players (and you have a psion in the party) then letting your party psion simply ignore one of the defining traits of the creature will eliminate a big part of the point of using the template in the first place.

Comment: Have you spoken with anyone from Rite Publishing or Dreamscarred Press? Do you have any reason to suspect *your personal opinion* is in fact *either of their opinion*? If so, please add it to your answer. If not, please do not put your opinion in their mouths, and do not mislead readers into thinking your opinion is anything more than your opinion. Your opinion can stand on its own, and it’s a perfectly reasonable opinion, but trying to ascribe greater importance to that is not OK. And RAI is a misleading term [that should be avoided](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7528/4563).

Comment: @KRyan I did not make affirmative statements about their opinion.  I noted that they were independent third parties, and the order of publication.  I noted the likelihood that there was not communication based on that.  I noted the sorts of things the ability protected against, and suggested that that was useful information *for making guesses*.

Comment: I don’t consider that appropriate, and consider this a bad answer as a result.

Comment: @KRyan could you please clarify what portion of my answer you consider to be misleading?

Comment: The part that claims other people you have never spoken to “probably” agree with your personal interpretation of circumstantial and inconclusive evidence. You have no way to know that this is even “probably” true and you therefore should not make that claim.

Comment: @KRyan I have edited it to remove the word and acronym you found so objectionable, in spite of the offense I took to your tone.  You might want to dial that part back.

Comment: Touchsight is from 3.5 Expanded Psionics Handbook, published by WotC 2004. Dreamscarred Press just didn't modify it when they imported psionics into Pathfinder. (Not that this has any rules weight, but if you want to argue about who might have been aware of each other...)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the name, *Touchsight* doesn't necessarily use your *touch* sense, it simply allows you to feel things around you. Hide from the World shows a list of things that it ignores and a list of things that can affect it, anything outside of that is entire *GM Fiat*.

- [true seeing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-seeing/);
- any other divination spell;
- it can also still be tracked using mundane means.

This makes me think that mundane touching can detect the trickster, but not magical (or psionic) touch. [Psychometabolism](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/) powers work similar to transmutation effects, which are not forms of divination and thus not excluded, and its described as a *"mental contact"*, so it is it's own thing, not covered by other rules.

> concealing the subject from **all senses** except touch.

Sight is a contact between reflected light and your eyes, smelling is a contact between airborne molecules and your nose, hearing is contact between sound waves and your ears, and tasting is a contact between a substance and your tongue. So, *Touchsight*, to me, is another sense entirely, that works exclusively in your brain, in response to psionic stimuli. And if that will work against *Hide from the World* is left at GM discretion.